# Oauth 1.0 on Windows 8

Tags: c#, oauth, .net-4.5, async-await

I'm trying to use OAuth 1.0 to authenticate my call to some webservice, This is my C# code:

```
OAuthBase oauth = new OAuthBase();
string normalizedUrl = String.Empty;
string normalizedqueryparameters = String.Empty;
string finalurl;
string sig;
var MerchantId = "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx";
var PublicKey = "xx";
var SecreteKey = "xxxxx";
var URL = new Uri("http://www.Server.com/DeveloperAPI/category/" + MerchantId + "/NA");
// token secret
sig = oauth.GenerateSignature(URL, PublicKey, SecreteKey, "", "", "POST", oauth.GenerateTimeStamp(), oauth.GenerateNonce(), out normalizedUrl, out normalizedqueryparameters);
finalurl = string.Format("{0}?{1}&oauth_signature={2}", normalizedUrl, normalizedqueryparameters, oauth.UrlEncode(sig));
string text = string.Empty;
using (var clinet = new HttpClient())
{
      clinet.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/Json");
      clinet.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Method", "POST");
      using (var response = await clinet.GetAsync(finalurl))
      {
           text = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
      }
}
```

I got the OAuthBase class from here:

http://code.google.com/p/oauth/issues/detail?id=223

Using Fiddler the Raw http request is this:

```
GET http://www.server.com/DeveloperAPI/category/d8d63626-99d7-4aff-abe7-542ad705d083/CK00001277?oauth_consumer_key=Rxxxx7LO&oauth_nonce=65xxx982&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1345xxxx20&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=PhUxxxxOh%2FzIxCo8A%2BQBNxxxxy7E%3D HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/Json
Method: POST
Host: www.xxxx.com
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Am I creating the HTTP call right?

Comment: Why do you tag the question with W8 and WinRT? It doesn't look to me like anything more than plain C# and a Google's library..

Comment: I tried to tag these as C#4.5 (or 5), but I couldnt find the tags. I'm using some Async operations.

Comment: I changed the tags. And getting back to the question - I don't see anything wrong. What happens? any exceptions? service returns an error? have you tried checking what is transmitted with i.e. wireshark ?

Comment: Thanks, I get an error back from the server. So, you are saying everything looks good? I should contact the web server admins. They have a website portal to test the API, and it worked. so I figured I did something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm.. really, I'd try looking at the HTTP request with WireShark first. It could be possible that, for example, that on the test server you get some redirects and extra preliminary auth cookies (which httpclient would store), and on the main - you do not and you must get them first before calling that sig-generator. Looking at the traffic is very easy, and it will make you sure about whether the difference is on your, or theirs side. Sometimes the webdevs are even more talkative when you present them a log file with the raw packets :)

Comment: I used Fiddler, and added the Raw http call to the question, it doesnt send it as a POST method, could that be the issue?

Comment: yes, it definitely may be it:)

Comment: Yes, Thank you, turns out it is the POST thing :)

Answer (score 1):

It turns the issue is that when I create the signature, I'm passing "POST", but the call is "GET" so this solves my issue:

```
sig = oauth.GenerateSignature(URL, PublicKey, SecreteKey, "", "", "GET", oauth.GenerateTimeStamp(), oauth.GenerateNonce(), out normalizedUrl, out normalizedqueryparameters);
```